# How can I write this query in exec('')?

Tags: sql-server-2005

Here, I am trying to create one dynamic query, but it is giving error :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_GetProductsbySales12
@top int,
@all bit,
@orderby nvarchar(20),
@orderdir nvarchar(30) 
as
begin

declare @sql nvarchar(2000)

set @sql = ('SELECT a.skucode,a.productCode,a.productName,a.totalOrder FROM 
    ( select top ')+cast(@top as nvarchar(50))+('  tblProducts.skuCode,tblProducts.productCode, tblProducts.productName, COUNT(tblOrders_Products.delivered) as totalOrder
 FROM         tblOrders_Products INNER JOIN 
                       tblProducts ON tblOrders_Products.productID = tblProducts.productID
 WHERE tblProducts.productName is not null
 GROUP BY tblOrders_Products.delivered, tblOrders_Products.productID, tblProducts.skuCode, tblProducts.productName,tblProducts.productCode
 ORDER BY totalOrder desc,tblProducts.skuCode  ) a
 ORDER BY case when  @orderdir = ''a'' and @orderby=''skucode'' then a.skuCode  end  , 
           case when  @orderdir = ''d'' and @orderby=''skucode'' then a.skuCode  end desc,

           case when  @orderdir = ''a'' and @orderby=''qty'' then a.totalOrder end,
          case when  @orderdir = ''a'' and @orderby=''qty'' then a.skuCode  end,
           case when  @orderdir = ''d'' and @orderby=''qty'' then a.totalOrder end desc,
          case when  @orderdir = ''d'' and @orderby=''qty'' then a.skuCode  end desc')
exec (@sql)


end
GO
```

I am getting error is

> Server: Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 8
>   Must declare the variable '@orderdir'.

Why I am getting this even though @orderdir is declared?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `sp_executesql` to pass in your variables.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx

```
exec sp_executesql @sql,
                   N'@orderdir nvarchar(30)',
                   @orderdir=@orderdir
```

Comment: +1. what was I thinking? I was trying to kep it simple for poster, but of course this is the way to do it.

Comment: Thanks!  If you want dynamic object names, your way is best.  A good way to avoid SQL injection is to wrap it in the `QUOTENAME()` function.

Comment: Hi, I just want to know what is difference between @ and @@ in sql server?

Comment: You should really post that as a new question ... it is not really relevant in this discussion.  Regardless, I believe @@ is reserved for server variables.